# Asus AiMesh setup fails

Tags: asus, mesh-networking

I'm having trouble setting up a 2-node AiMesh network with two Asus ROG GT-AX11000 routers. I have followed the instructions and

1. have the latest firmware on both routers (3.0.4.386_41700)
2. factory-reset the node (but the main router has a custom SSID and some fixed DHCP IP assignments)
3. placed the routers within approx 3 meters

When searching for an AiMesh node from the web interface of the main router, it finds my node and lists its MAC address. However, after I click the button to connect to it, I get a spinning progress indicator for a while (up to about 35%) and then I get an error message, listing the following possible causes:

1. someone else is trying to set up an AiMesh system (no, it is just me here)
2. the routers should be within 3 metres (they are)
3. the Node should be powered on (it is)
4. the Node must be upgraded to AiMesh supported firmware (it is)
5. the Node must be reset to default (it is, and it publishes an ASUS_30_5G SSID)

Did anyone else encounter this and find a solution? I would rather not factory-reset the main router if I don't need to. (And the instructions from Asus do not indicate that that should be necessary.)

Comment: As a follow-up question, given the topology I want with just one main router and one node connected with cable, maybe I don't have to care about AiMesh and can rather set the node up in AP mode as described, e.g., here? https://networkingguides.com/connect-two-routers/ I guess that would give the same performance?

Comment: All I can say is it took me three hours and many tries to set them up. In the end, it took over 10 minutes for the routers to synchronize. Because the process is fully automatic anyway you can just let them be and check back later.